# how to declare Array of image in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to call a image from array of object, for this purpose I have written below code

```
product: any[] = [{
    id: 121, name: "iphone", url: 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png'
}] //I tried locale file path also
```

And calling this image like below

```
<div *ngFor="let list of product">
    {{list.url}}
</div>
```

but it is not showing image rather than it showing only string. Could any one please let me know how to call a image which is defined in array

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `img` tag to render image into view part within your iteration.

Try this -

```
<div *ngFor="let list of product">
    <img [src]='list.url' />
</div>
```

## [Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jytjaw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 2):

Put URL in `<img>` tag with source binding:

```
<div *ngFor="let list of product">
    <img [src]='list.url' [alt]='list.name'/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this solution

```
<div *ngFor="let list of product">
    <img [src]='list.url'/>
</div
```